# smartphone-like / touch-device behavior in Chromium 41 and Opera browsers in VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, chromium, browser, opera

I use Chromium and Opera browsers in my VirtualBox v.4.3.26 (Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome), but few days ago (not clear, whether after an update or I inadvertently changed some settings) they started to behave as browsers in a smartphone(?).

- right-clicking with mouse there is no reaction;
- when scrolling with mouse it either selects the text or images where the cursor is, or when just scrolling over a link it would go to the linked site;
- in search tabs, when double-clicking it would show one or two blue drops below the search tab, and there is a text (Cut | Copy | Paste | ...) above the search bar.

http://tinypic.com/r/jqgikp/8

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivqci.jpg

I've already tried to purge and reinstall Chromium, but the same smartphone-like behavior appeared again. I also use Firefox browser which is running fine.

Thank you for any suggestions on how to solve this issue!

Comment: What is the resolution of your virtual machine set to? Some browsers use the resolution of your display to try and determining whether or not you are mobile.

Comment: @Donald the resolution is set to 1366x649 http://imgur.com/8khwM3H but I also tried to reset it to the original resolution of my laptop 1366x768 http://imgur.com/FcAZj03 and after the restart, it displayed the same smartphone-like behavior. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, that's not it then... I am stumped. Sorry!

Comment: @Donald so it seems it is a known issue by chromium developers related to virtual machine and Chromium 41 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=456222

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed in [Chromium Issue 465660](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465660) worked for me.
Go to Terminal and run

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
```

Find this line in the file:

```
Exec=chromium-browser %U
```

Then replace it with:

```
Exec=chromium-browser --touch-devices=123 %U
```